# Groups and subgroups in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have some groups and some items in Meteor.

Each item belongs to a group. The groups can actually be splitted in two where some of the groups belong to a group with a higher order (in a hierarchy).

So the hierarchy could look like:

```
Group 1
    Subgroup 1
    Subgroup 2
    Subgroup 3
Group 2
    Subgroup 1
    Subgroup 2
Group 3
    Supgroup 1
```

The items can only belong to a subgroup and never a 'main group'. So I thought I could create a collection which only consists of subgroups and then have a field telling to which 'main group' this subgroup belongs. But I also need to store additional information about the 'main groups' (such as its name, date range, etc.), so maybe a better solution is to either create two collections; `MainGroup` and `SubGroup`, and have a `SubGroupId` field in `Item`. But since the two type of groups are almost equal, I think I can make a schema structure where the subgroups are child objects of a 'main group'.

How do you normally create the data structure of such app? Ideally, it would also be possible to have nested groups someday.

Answer (score 0):

Since you intend to have nested group one day it doesn't make much sense to have two collections (one for each level) since your then need another collection for each further love you have.

In a traditional Mongo setup you'd include the subgroup inside the document for each main groups. This might be a sensible approach in your case.

An alternative would be to have a single collection of groups, where each group can have a parent ID as a field. If there's no parent ID then you know it's a top level group. This approach is useful if you need to sent just the subgroups down to the client (since Meteor can't return a cursor for a sub-collection you'll always need to send the hold sub-document down).

The best structure therefore depends on your app and how you'll be using the data to create your UI.

Finally, as note by another poster you can use the [Simple Schema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema) package to enforce a schema once you've decided on it.

Answer (score -2):

What you need is a schema package like https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema

Simple schemas

```
 AddressSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  street: {
    type: String,
    max: 100
  },
  city: {
    type: String,
    max: 50
  },
  state: {
    type: String,
    regEx: /^A[LKSZRAEP]|C[AOT]$/
  },
  zip: {
    type: String,
    regEx: /^[0-9]{5}$/
  }
});
```

Compound schemas

```
CustomerSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  billingAddress: {
    type: AddressSchema
  },
  shippingAddresses: {
    type: [AddressSchema],
    minCount: 1
  }
});
```

To validate an object

```
obj = {title: "Ulysses", author: "James Joyce"};
isValid = BookSchema.namedContext("myContext").validate(obj);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: That's explaining how to enforce a schema. The user's asking what sort of schema to enforce in order to best address the data he's trying to represent.